# R How do I find and plot the intersection of many halfspaces?

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I am looking for an algorithm or (preferably) a package in R that can find the intersection of many halfspaces and then plot their intersection.

I'll define the problem mathematically. Suppose you have a collection of N halfspaces defined to be S_i = {(x,y)|y >= a_i + b_i * x} for i = 1,2,...,N where x and y are real numbers and a_i and b_i are fixed real numbers. I know (a_i,b_i) for i = 1,2,...,N. I need to find the set S = S_1 intersect S_2 intersect ... intersect S_N and then plot S. An example of what I am looking for is below.

[image: halfspace intersection]

The thin lined blue region is the intersection of the halfspaces S and the thick blue lines are the halfspace boundaries, y = a_i + b_i * x. I don't want the boundaries outside the intersection to be plotted, they are there to make this example clear. Please ignore the orange arrow and the dots.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your problem resembles the definition of a convex hull although the points defining the hull would be the line intersections. There are packages that define convex hulls from data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not give any explicit examples of the lines that you want nor the data structure that you are using to store the lines, so I just give some example. I have the lines as functions. You can choose a range of x values that extends beyond the region you want to plot and find the largest value of the L(x) for each x.  Use these to plot a polygon showing the desired region.   I make two plots, with and without the boundary lines, to show how the region fits the line.

```
L1 = function(x) { -0.25 - 1*x }
L2 = function(x) { -0.25 - 0.6*x }
L3 = function(x) { -0.25 - 0.3*x }
L4 = function(x) { -0.3  - 1.5*x }


x=seq(-1,1,0.01)
Y = pmax(L1(x), L2(x), L3(x), L4(x))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(NULL, xlim=c(-0.5,0.5), ylim=c(-0.5,0.5))
polygon(c(-1,x,1),c(2,Y,2), col="blue", density=10)

plot(NULL, xlim=c(-0.5,0.5), ylim=c(-0.5,0.5))
polygon(c(-1,x,1),c(2,Y,2), col="blue", density=10)

lines(x, L1(x))
lines(x, L2(x))
lines(x, L3(x))
lines(x, L4(x))
```

[image: Polygon]